# Computing the stabilizer of a set

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ symbols, and let $A$ be a subset of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$. I would like to compute the subgroup of $S_n$ consisting of all permutations that fix $A$ as a set; in other words, the permutations that map $A$ to itself. Are there relatively efficient algorithms for doing this? In Magma and GAP I have found functionality for computing the permutations that fix every element of $A$, but that is not what I want.

Comment: The elements of ${\rm Perm}(X)$ that stabilize a subset $A\subseteq X$ are precisely those in the internal direct product ${\rm Perm}(A)\times{\rm Perm}(X\setminus A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment got there before me, but I've filled in the details:

Let $\{1,\ldots,n\}=A\sqcup B$ and $H$ be the subgroup of $S_n$ fixing $A$ setwise. Let $S_A$ be the subgroup of $S_n$ fixing $A$ pointwise and $S_B$ be the subgroup of $S_n$ fixing $B$ pointwise.

The elements of $S_n$ which fix $A$ as a set are precisely those that fix $A$ as a set and fix $B$ as a set.

Let $g\in H$. Define $g_A\in S_n$ such that $a^{g_A}=a^g$ for $a\in A$ and $b^{g_A}=b$ for $b\in B$. This means $g_A\in S_A$. Define $g_B\in S_n$ such that $b^{g_B}=b^g$ for $b\in B$ and $a^{g_B}=a$ for $a\in A$. This means $g_B\in S_B$.

It's easy to check that $g=g_Ag_B$ and then therefore that $H=S_BS_A\cong S_{|A|}\times S_{|B|}$.

As you have stated, you can compute $S_A$ and $S_B$ in MAGMA or GAP.